# quillJS symbols instead of tags

Tags: markdown, pandoc, asciidoc, quill

I don't get how to add specific characters instead of tags in quillJS. 
I wanna use it as an markdown / asciiDoc editor.
I got stuck at 2 points at the moment:

1. adding characters by pressing a button instead of tags.
2. setting/checking the status for a specific character range to active

Thanks in advance